# Match Specific Printer Command Pattern

Tags: c#, .net

i will be sending some commands to printer which will  be of this format.

```
{AA00:00;|}
{AAB08:02;|}
```

where { is always the first character, } is always the end character,|is always the last but one character. in between these i will have specific commands AA00:00; and this may vary.

I want to check these format in regex and I am new to regex, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "i will have specific commands AA00:00; and this may vary."  By how much will this vary? Is "{AAB08:02;|}" a valid command?

Comment: vary in name and number.for example AA may be ABC, ABCD and Number may be 00,0000,0 and the command will be as ABC00,ABCD0,AA0000 like this.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

I misread your comment about the numbers and thought commas were acceptable.

Try this pattern

```
"^{[A-Z]+\\d+:\\d+;\\|}$"
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - Beginning of the line
- `{[A-Z]+` - An open bracket following by 1 or more capital letters
- `\\d+` - One or more numbers
- `:` - The colon character
- `;` - The semi-colon character
- `\\|}` - The pipe character followed by the close bracket
- `$` - The end of the line

Code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] commands = 
        {
            "{AA00:00;|}",
            "{ABC0:93;||}",
            "{AAB08:02;|}",
            "{123AA:AA;|}",
            "{AA123,123:123,123;|}"
        };

        foreach (string command in commands)
        {
            if (Regex.Match(command, "^{[A-Z]+\\d+:\\d+;\\|}$").Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good command");
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bad command");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Good command
Bad command
Good command
Bad command
Bad command
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/THAehg)

Comment: We both *evolved* into the same answer, +1. I did borrow the list of examples though. :-)

Comment: @Jayasri Choose this answer above mine if you use this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

How about an easier to understand pattern?

`^{[A-Z]+\d+:\d+;\|}$";`

- `^` - Beginning of line, doesn't move (search) within the text; an anchor
- `{` - Literal brace.
- `[A-Z]+` An uppercase letter in set `[ ]` A-Z, one or more of them `+`
- `\d+` A digit (0-9) `\d`, one or more of them `+`
- `:` - Literal colon
- `\d+` A digit (0-9) `\d`, one or more of them `+`
- `;` - Literal semi-colon
- `\|` - Literal pipe, escaped for the regex parser, not the C# parser
- `}` - Literal brace.
- `$` - End of regex parsing in data; an anchor

Note I use `+` because it avoids the problems of `*` (zero or more) because the more *hints* we can give a regex parser, the faster it will perform. 1 or more is better than zero or more because it can cause the parser to backtrack other possible combinations. We want to be as concise as possible.

**Code**

```
var pattern = @"^{[A-Z]+\d+:\d+;\|}$";

var commands = new List<string>()
        {
            "{AA00:00;|}",            // Good
            "{ABC0:93;||}",           // Bad too many '|'
            "{AAB08:02;|}",           // Good
            "{123AA:AA;|}",           // Bad can't start with a number
            "{1111:11;|}",            // Bad
            "{*A11:11;|}",            // Bad
            "{AA123,123:123,123;|}"   // Bad can't have a comma
        };

commands.Select (cmd => string.Format("{0,-25} : {1}", 
                                      cmd, 
                                      Regex.IsMatch(cmd, pattern) ? "Valid" : "Not Valid"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(result => Console.WriteLine (result));
```

**Result**

```
{AA00:00;|}               : Valid
{ABC0:93;||}              : Not Valid
{AAB08:02;|}              : Valid
{123AA:AA;|}              : Not Valid
{1111:11;|}               : Not Valid
{*A11:11;|}               : Not Valid
{AA123,123:123,123;|}     : Not Valid
```

Comment: @Shar1er80 Thanks for letting me know of the issues and they are resolved. As to copying your answer, the answer is your pattern, and that **time** your pattern had `,` in as valid character. Mine did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `{\w{2}\d{2}:\d{2};\|}`

- `\w{2}`: this pattern find two alfanumeric chars;
- `\d{2}`: this pattern find two numeric chars;
- `\|`: this pattern find the character "|".